# Help needed to identify a relatively old film

Tags: story-identification

I need your help to identify an old sci-film. I remember that the film started with a voice-over, saying that in a certain year of the future, USA established that people have the right to life but also the right to death.

The implications was that insurance companies bought the lives of groups of people (then decided the death-date of a person).

Comment: Any renown actors in it?

Comment: How "old" are we talking? Black and white or color? How long ago did you watch it?

Comment: Were the deaths enforced by some sci-fi means?

Comment: Are you sure it was a film and not an anthology TV show like Outer Limits or Twilight Zone?

Comment: It was a color film, early 90's. It was a film not an anthology TV show. I remember people who sold their lives, they signed a contract to give their body to insurance companies after a number of years.

Comment: @Frank: You can [edit your questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: Color film, early 90s = "relatively old". *Sigh* there goes any hope of my feeling young.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Death Collector (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0228196/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). Tagline:  In the not too distant future there is no justice ... just insurance.

Plot summary from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0228196/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1):

> In a future time, when things have reverted back to the days of the Old West, a man goes after the gang that murdered his brother.